# Stripe invoice.payment_succeeded event upon subscription cancellation

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a 12 euros/month stripe subscription with a cancel_at field set to 29 march . I noticed yesterday that an invoice.payment_succeeded event was sent to me as long as the subscription deleted event.
I don't want the customer to be charged upon his subscription cancellation so I don't know why I got this invoice in the screenshot with 8 euros or so..
I cancelled my subscription through API by setting a cancel_at field and I don't want any refund for my customers and after a long chat with Stripe support they told me that there is no way to disable proration upon setting a cancel_at date.
PS: no payment was shown in the payments page but I am afraid that in future cases Stripe will charge my customer..
[image]

[image]

Comment: this is an off-invoice/negative-invoice (see brackets (...) around numbers). That means stripe initially charged 12 euros and when the customer canceled his subscription, they refunded for unused days.

Comment: Maybe for the next time: blur out the invoice id and customer email.

Comment: @NomanGul thank you that's right ..  according the answer of Paul Asjes , the refund didn't actually take place. It's up to me to choose whether to refund or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your customer wasn't charged anything. If you look at the top of the invoice page it shows that it was for 0 euros. Invoices for zero currency aren't sent to the user.

The invoice has an invoice item of unused time for -8.92 euros. This is the time which the user paid for but never got as you cancelled the subscription before the end of the billing cycle.

It's up to you if you want to refund the customer this or just ignore it.

Comment: Thank you so much for this clear answer ! Can you tell me what should I do in case I chose one day to refund this amount ? I wanna make sure that stripe doesn't refund unless I choose so .

Comment: You'd create a refund for that amount either via the API or the dashboard. Stripe would never refund that unless explicitly told to.

Comment: One last question : in the code where I capture the invoice.payment_succeeded what condition do I put in order to differentiate between a normal invoice and this kind of invoices? is checking for a 0 paid amount sufficient or I can check if payment_intent  is null ?